# How to trigger pipeline for tags and changes in specific dir

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, npm-publish

I have two jobs (for two npm packages):

```
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
    changes:
      - packages/a/**/*
...
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
    changes:
      - packages/b/**/*
```

I would like to trigger job a only when tags are pushed with changes in `packages/a/**/*`.
And same for b with change in path `packages/b/**/*`.

In each folder is `package.json`.

The problem is when I run `npm version patch` for **a** and push it that will trigger both pipelines, but change is only in `packages/a/package.json`. I don`t understand why.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, I was having the same issue but I don't think it can be done (see answer). Did you manage to solve this in an alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might not be possible to do this. According to [GitLab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges)

> You can use `rules: changes` with other pipeline types, but it is not recommended because `rules: changes` always evaluates to true when there is no Git push event. Tag pipelines, scheduled pipelines, and so on do not have a Git push event associated with them. A `rules: changes` job is always added to those pipeline if there is no `if:` statement that limits the job to branch or merge request pipelines.